# Displaying leading zeroes in a timer xcode

Tags: xcode, nstimer

I'm tying to display a countdown in my app. The timer works fine but I want it to display the time as 00:00:00. Leading zeroes on single digit integers are not ordinarily displayed (eg. 0:1:15) but I can't figure out how to get them in without resorting to clunky if-statements. Here is the relevant code:

```
-(void)timerFireMethod: (NSTimer *)timer {

   [self setUpTimer];
   self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu:%lu:%lu", self.timerParts.hour, self.timerParts.minute, self.timerParts.second];

   self.counter--; }
```

Does anyone know what I can do to have the leading zeroes displayed so 0:1:15 becomes 00:01:15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force to display leading zeros by adding `.2`.
It displays always two digits, in case of < 10 with a leading zero.

```
self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2lu:%.2lu:%.2lu", self.timerParts.hour, self.timerParts.minute, self.timerParts.second];
```